# Cannot find the excutables generated by Xcode

Tags: xcode, build

I have an Xcode project with these targets

[image]

and I built them. I found the folder where the build gets put in. But I cannot find the target files.

[image]

All I see are those `.framework` files. I am interested in the `unar` and `lsar` executables. What do I have to do to get them when I run a build?